# The version of python used by Apache Spark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

What version of python does Apache Spark libraries support (2 or 3)?
If it supports both versions, Is there any performance considerations to use python 2 or 3 when using Apache-Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least since Spark 1.2.1 a default Python version is 2.7 if not set otherwise using `PYSPARK_PYTHON` or `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` (see [`bin/pyspark`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L38)).

Python 3 is supported since Spark 1.4.0 (see [SPARK-4897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4897) and [Spark 1.4.0 release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-4-0.html)).

Choosing one over another should depend on your requirements. It is probably wise to read [Should I use Python 2 or Python 3 for my development activity?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) if you're not sure. Beyond that it is most likely far to broad and subjective topic for SO.